# Google Drive for Desktop accessible between multiple Windows users

Tags: windows, permissions, users, google-drive-for-desktop

I have 2 Windows 10 accounts:

- `Home` account (Administrator)
- `Work` account (Administrator)

On my `Home` account I have installed Google Drive (accessible on `E:\` drive).

When I start Google Drive on `Home` account and switch to `Work` account, I can see "E:" Drive but it is not accessible:

[image: Error]

My question is: how can I see `E:\` drive content on `Work` Account without installing Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Google Drive for desktop application is running and signed in to the same google account for both users. Some applications run instances based on which user is signed in at the moment. If the google drive application isn't running and signed in while using the Work account you will see the drive but cannot access it.